# How to unit test extraction from cookie in Gin Gonic

Tags: unit-testing, go, cookies, go-gin

I'm using [gin gonic](https://github.com/gin-gonic). I've a function that extracts a token from a cookie, which actually works. I'm using this function in a route handler and want to test the handler function, but I don't know how.

**Function:**

```
// Extracts token from a cookie
func tokenFromCookie(c *gin.Context, name string) (string, error) {
    token, err := c.Cookie(name)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return token, nil
}
```

**Route:**

```
func RefreshTokenHandler(accessTokenKey string, refreshTokenKey string) gin.HandlerFunc {
fn := func(c *gin.Context) {
    token, err := tokenFromCookie(c, "refresh_token")
    if err != nil {
        _ = c.Error(err).SetMeta(noCookie)
        return
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "token":  token,
    })
})
```

**Route definition:**

```
func CreateRoutes(r *gin.Engine) *gin.Engine {

    r.Use(errorHandler)

    // Auth
    auth := r.Group("/auth")
    {
        auth.GET("/refresh-token", RefreshTokenHandler(accessTokenSignatureKey, refreshTokenSignatureKey))
    }

    return r
}
```

**Unit test**:

```
func TestRefreshTokenHandler(t *testing.T) {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/auth/refresh-token", nil)
    req.AddCookie(&http.Cookie{
        Name: "refresh_token",
        Value:  "token",
        MaxAge:   604800, 
        Expires:  time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24 * 7),
        Path:     "/",
        Domain:   "127.0.0.1",
        HttpOnly: true,
        SameSite: http.SameSiteNoneMode,
        Secure:   secure
        }
    )

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    router.ServeHTTP(w, req)
    got := w.Code
    if gotCode != 200 {
        t.Errorf("GET /auth/refresh-token; got %d, want 200", got)
    }
}
```

The **tokenFromCookie()** function throws an error though:

```
http: named cookie not present
```

This is a similar unit test that I found in the [gin gonic repo](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/context_test.go#L615):

```
func TestContextGetCookie(t *testing.T) {
    c, _ := CreateTestContext(httptest.NewRecorder())
    c.Request, _ = http.NewRequest("GET", "/get", nil)
    c.Request.Header.Set("Cookie", "user=gin")
    cookie, _ := c.Cookie("user")
    assert.Equal(t, "gin", cookie)

    _, err := c.Cookie("nokey")
    assert.Error(t, err)
}
```

Yet I don't understand why my code doesn't work and how to re-write it.

Comment: `"quantoras_refresh_token""` != `"refresh_token"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint! I simply forgot to anonymize this part, the names in my functions are actually equal. Do you mind editing your comment and replace the prefix with "foo"? Thank you big times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the list cookies you can try this:

```
fmt.Println(c.Request.Cookies())
```

I don't understand the point of creating new function tokenFromCookie.

```
func RefreshTokenHandler(accessTokenKey string, refreshTokenKey string) gin.HandlerFunc {
fn := func(c *gin.Context) {
    //token, err := tokenFromCookie(c, "refresh_token")
    token, err := c.Cookie("refresh_token")
    if err != nil {
        _ = c.Error(err).SetMeta(noCookie)
        return
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "token":  token,
    })
})
```

Comment: token, err := c.Cookie("refresh_token") did the trick, my tokenFromCookie was unnecessary indeed. Thank you!